# Flip Animation in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, animation

I'm creating a PowerPoint presentation with some index cards and would like to be able to 'flip' to the back of the card.

This tutorial shows [How to Build a Flip Custom Animation Effect in PowerPoint](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/articles/building_flip_custom_animation_effect_in_powerpoint.html), but only targets 2003 and 2007 because it uses Stretch and Collapse effects that are deprecated in 2010.

Are there any other ways to get the same effect?  Is seems like a relatively simple presentational animation, but a bit of googling didn't reveal anything promising.

If it wasn't clear, I'm looking for something like:

[image]