# How can I perform a "flip over a card" animation using PPT 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create an animation using PPT 2010 that will look like I'm flipping over a rectangular card, i.e., will look like I'm rotating the card with respect to its vertical axis. Is there an easy way to do this?

The built-in Swivel animation seems to do nearly what I want, but it rotates the object 360 degrees, and I want to rotate it only 180 degrees, i.e., as if I'm flipping an object over.

My ultimate goal is to make it look like I'm flipping an object over to reveal something written on the back side. If there's a better way to approach this problem than a "flip" effect, I'm all ears.

UPDATE: It looks like this is the same question as [Flip Animation in PowerPoint 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/751354/flip-animation-in-powerpoint-2010).

Comment: Any video that can demonstrate what you want to do for visual learners like me?

Comment: Weird that you can't dictate how many revolutions swivel does.  Otherwise I would get swivel to do 180 and go blank, and have another rectangle over it that swivels at the same time but starting from blank.

Comment: @Paul: I was planning to do something like that, but Swivel doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I know you probably don't need it anymore (since this was posted about a year ago) but Select for Best Answer for future reference so no one has to go through the trial and error. Just got it to work with only a few animations.

Assuming F is the front image, and B is the back image, it goes like this:

```
B: Swivel (Entrance) - On Click, 3 second duration, no delay
B: Disappear (Exit) - With Previous, Auto duration, no delay
B: Appear (Entrance) - With Previous, Auto duration, 2.4 second delay
F: Swivel (Exit) - With Previous, 3 second duration, 1.8 second delay
F: Disappear (Exit) - With Previous, Auto duration, 2.4 second delay

Total Animation time: 6 seconds
```

Note if you want a faster swivel, just reduce it porportionally. (i.e. If you want a 2 second animation, divide duration and delays by 3, etc...)

Hope this helps everyone! :D

Comment: This is useful, but I still think the simplest approach is to copy the animation from objects created with PPT 2007, where stretch and collapse animations are supported. Details are available at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-can-i-perform-a-flip-over-a-card-animation/33337135-0a96-4524-b398-d97cf0d9d570

Answer (score 1):

With your object, first attach a swivel *exit* animation, and set its timing to be "slow" - 3 seconds.

Then attach a "disappear" exit animation, but set it's delay to be .6 seconds, and set it to "start with previous", so that it starts at the same time as the swivel, but doesn't do the disappear until .6 seconds.

This means that the swivel will start on a click, but then disappear entirely when it gets to the sideways on point, which is at the .6 second mark.

So that is the top card disappearing.

For the "back", you use a swivel entrance, but it needs to be hidden from view until it has reached the right point in the swivel.  You can't combine entrance animations, so you need a third object that sits between the "front" and the "back" object.  This should be the same colour as the slide background, have a "disappear" animation, set to start at the same time as the swivel for the "back" object, but with a delay of 2.5 seconds.

So the swivel starts for the "Back" object, but it isn't seen because there is an opaque object over the top of it.  At 2.5 seconds, the opaque object disappears and you see the end of the swivel for the "Back" object, which at 2.5 seconds appears to be when it is sideways on.

You'll need to start the "Back" swivel animation prior to the first object, because it appears to do three turns before completing.  So you want it to appear when it is sideways on in the last revolution, and then have the Appear animation kick in then, so that the previous object's Disappear and this ones Appear coincide.

If you get the timing right, it should look like the object flipping over.

Comment: The first part works fine (having the top card disappear), but I can't get the second part to work. It has to start swiveling while invisible, and I can't figure out how to do that. Help?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Damn, yes, I didn't notice, but the swivel entrance overrides the appear animation, so they need to be on separate objects.  Updated the answer.  I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: I've played around with this some more, and I don't think it will work. The problems is that the swivel animation makes three turns. We want the first turn of the top object and the last turn of the bottom object, but we don't want the second turn at all. During the animation, nothing happens during the time taken by that turn: the top object has disappeared, but the bottom object hasn't yet appeared.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Yeah, that is why I suggested starting the bottom swivel at the same time as the top one, but with a slight delay.  The best bet is to put the top and bottom objects next to each other, so you can get the timings right on the swivels before overlaying them.

Comment: I just don't see how it can work. You want to spend half the "flip" time with what looks like a 90-degree turn and the other half with what looks like another 90-degree turn, but what looks like a 90-degree turn in Swivel takes less than half the time of the animation.

Comment: With the top one, we want just the first part of the swivel, then we hide it.  As it hides, we want the last part of the back swivel to unhide.  So the back swivel must start with the same trigger as the front swivel, but it starts *first*, the front swivel is delayed.  I think this is the counter intuitive part.

Comment: Ah, yes I see now. Thanks for the clarification. It looks like a much simpler approach to achieving this effect is to copy the animation from objects created with PPT 2007, where stretch and collapse animations are supported. Details are available at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-can-i-perform-a-flip-over-a-card-animation/33337135-0a96-4524-b398-d97cf0d9d570.

Answer (score 1):

The above information on setting up flip over card work with a couple of minor tweeks. It did take me a few minutes to adjust the timings and selecting the right animation. The following may help with the timing and the animation settings that I put in for a nine second swivel duration which equals 5 half turns.

Front object settings:

1. Exit Basic Swivel, Start On Click, Duration 9.00 seconds
2. Exit Disappear, Start With Previous, Delay 1.8 seconds
   Object between Settings:
3. Exit Disappear, Start With Previous, Delay 1.8 seconds
   Rear object settings:
4. Entrance Basic Swivel, Start With Previous, Duration 9.00 seconds, Delay 1.8 seconds
   Object between Settings:
5. Entrance Appear, Start With Previous, Delay 5.4 seconds
   Front object settings:
6. Entrance Basic Swivel, Start With Previous, Duration 9 seconds, Delay 5.4 seconds
   Object between settings:
7. Exit Disappear, Start With Previous, Delay 9.00 seconds
   Rear object settings:
8. Entrance Basic Swivel, Start With Previous, Duration 9.00 seconds, Delay 9.00 seconds
   Object between settings:
9. Entrance Appear, Start With Previous, Delay 12.6 seconds
   Front object settings:
10. Entrance Basic Swivel, Start With Previous, Duration 9.00 seconds, Delay 12.6 seconds

Finishing off is up to the individual but I finished off with the following.

Front object settings:

1. Exit Disappear, Start With Previous, Delay 14.4 seconds
   Inserted original Front Object without any animations attached and added the following:
2. Entrance Appear, Start With Previous, Delay 14.4 seconds

Remember that the total duration time of the swivel should be divided by five as that's how many quarter turns there are in the animation. Depending on it being an Entrance or exit as it will start or finish with a fifth of its duration at this point before turning or exiting. So when you want the next slide to appear just divide duration by five and double it.

Cameron

Comment: I'm upvoting this, but not marking it as the accepted answer, because I still think the best approach is the one I mentioned in an earlier comment: copy the animation from objects created with PPT 2007, where stretch and collapse animations are supported. Details are available at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-can-i-perform-a-flip-over-a-card-animation/33337135-0a96-4524-b398-d97cf0d9d570